# How to get div to honor margin-top

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I have a div container that clears the floats and specifies a margin-top. But the margin-top does not work.

I am trying to set a height: 100% on the prior div in the document flow but that does not work.

See form at https://sportame.net/sandbox/matthew/sandbox/matthew/index.php

I want the "Customer Information" block to have a margin-top.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: _“See form at”_ - no, see [ask] and [mcve]. With >3k rep you should know by now that code relevant to your question, belongs directly into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just give `overflow: hidden` to `#tourInformation`. You have uncleared floats:

```css
#tourInformation {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And do the same for each section.

[image: preview]

Also the right way of doing this should be adding a `clearfix` class to the headings and making them like:

```css
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```